# Coerce to boolean

Tags: ruby

Given an expression which may return either a truthy value or nil,

```ruby
truthy_or_nil = [true, 'truthy', nil].sample
```

how can I coerce the result into a boolean without my colleagues or [linter](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) complaining?

```ruby
!!truthy_or_nil # Hard to see the !! on a long line, unclear
truthy_or_nil || false # Linter complains "you can simplify this"
!truthy_or_nil.nil? # Unclear on a long line
truthy_or_nil ? true : false # Hard to see on long line, too much typing
```

I have looked at the following questions and found them to be unrelated:

- [Why use !! to coerce a variable to boolean for use in a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648179/why-use-to-coerce-a-variable-to-boolean-for-use-in-a-conditional-expression) - This question is more specific than my question because it is about use of `!!` in conditional expressions.  Also, it's about JS.
- [In environments that take Boolean arguments, is it a good idea to wrap all functions instead of allowing them to be implicitly coerced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387032/in-environments-that-take-boolean-arguments-is-it-a-good-idea-to-wrap-all-funct) - This question is more about the merit of the technique than the technique itself.

If this question is determined to be [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), I will understand.  If so, is there a better place to ask it?

Comment: Why not create a method coerce_into_boolean and use that?

Comment: Really, `!!` is unclear? It's usually the idiomatic way to do something like this.

Comment: I was tempted at first to use the [wannabe_bool](https://github.com/prodis/wannabe_bool) gem, but I don't agree that `'off'.to_b` should `== false`

Comment: If you don't like wannabe_bool then why don't you adapt what it does to suit you? The implementation can't be terribly difficult. Also, you keep complaining about "long lines" so maybe you should simplify your code so that you don't have so many long lines.

Comment: You can add `true & truthy_or_nil` to your list. This uses [TrueClass#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/TrueClass.html#method-i-26).

Comment: It's good to know that `!!` is a common idiom, thanks.  I think idioms can still be unclear if you have never encountered them, but I'm more likely to use it if I know that others will understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution is to create a method in Kernel à la [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-Array), [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-String) etc.:

```
module Kernel
  def Boolean val
    !!val
  end
end
```

You could also add `to_bool`<sup>†</sup> to Object, à la `to_s`:

```
class Object
  def to_bool
    !!self
  end
end
```

Or do both and have one call the other. Barring either of these, I’d say `!!x` is the most common idiom, but is lesser known to those without a C background from what I’ve seen.

<sup><sup>†</sup>Really, this should probably be `to_b` to keep in-line with `to_a` vs. `to_ary`, etc. ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11182052/211563)). But `to_b` seems ambiguous to me (to bytes? to binary?).</sup>

Comment: Very interesting.  I didn't know of Kernel.Array and the rest.  I also didn't know you could have a method name begin with a capital letter!

Comment: @JaredBeck Note that Kernel#Array and the like all mostly call coercion methods on the object, e.g. `to_ary`/`to_a` (read about [the difference between those two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11182052/211563))

Comment: Apparently after 40K points you get the power to create footnotes :)

Comment: @MarkThomas No, you just need to be level 25 and have a +10 bonus in your Markdown Ninja skill, and be level 10 in HTML. ;)

Comment: @MarkThomas @Doorknob you just need <sup>er powers `;)`